# Trying to insert a node instead getting repeated values

Tags: data-structures, struct, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to add nodes to the beginning of a linked list. The program asks the user to input the number of names he wants to enter, so if I put 3 it is supposed to ask me for 3 different names and show them in a list, instead the program is printing the same name repeatedly.

```
    struct node{

      char data[20];
      struct node* link;

    }Damn;


    struct node* head;

    //Insert
    void Insert(char p[20]){

      struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      strncpy(Damn.data, p);
      temp->link = head;
      head = temp;
    }

   //Print
    void Print()
    {
      struct node* temp = head;
      while(temp != NULL){
        printf(" %s \n", Damn.data );
        temp = temp->link;
      }
    }


    //Main
    int main(){

      head = NULL;

      int i, n;
      char p[20];

      printf("How many names you want to enter\n");
      scanf("%d", &n);

      for(i=1; i<(n+1); i++){
        printf("Enter the %dth  name", i);
        scanf("%s", p);
        Insert(p);
        Print();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Damn.data` put `temp->data`. In addition, [strncpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) takes three arguments. You should add the maximum number of characters to be copied as a third argument.

Comment: hey thanks! it worked after I replaced Damn.data with temp->data. Also, I used strcpy instead of strncpy(), so its working fine now. But, I would like to ask why was it not working with Damn.data, seemed legit to me. Any idea?

Comment: Since you didn't *typedef* your Damn struct definition, it is also a small block of global-scope memory that is uninitialized.  But your new node is a segment of heap memory that malloc gave you, and is in the *temp* pointer.  Your original code attempted to copy the new string into that useless block of global-scope memory, rather than the proper heap-allocated block memory.  If you had typedef'ed the Damn struct definition, then the compiler would have thrown an error on the strncpy statement and you would have known that line was wrong.